# UIView subclasses default properties

Tags: iphone, cocoa-touch, uiview

What's the proper way to set a default value for a UIView subclass's property?

Although I'm not using them yet, if the XIB provides a value I'd like it to override the default. But if the XIB doesn't provide a value, I'd like my default value.

In this case, I'm thinking of a CGFloat value specifically. While it could be set to 0.0 this isn't a useful default, so checking for a value of 0.0 in my code and replacing it with a better value is something I'd rather avoid.

Comment: What property?  UIView has many.

Comment: Oh, my bad. Custom property of the subclass. In this case, it's called `lineWidth`.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Implement initWithFrame: in your subclass and set the property there.

```
- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)aRect {
    if (self = [super initWithFrame:aRect]) {
        // Set whatever properties you want.  For example...
        self.alpha = 0.75;
    }
    return self;
}
```

This designated initializer only executes if the view is constructed in code.  If the view comes from a nib file, it will get initialized using initWithCoder:, which modifies the attributes to match the attributes in the nib file.  To handle this case you can override initWithCoder:, test to see if the attribute is set to its default value, and if so, change it:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        if (self.alpha == 1.0) {
            self.alpha = 0.20;
        }
    }
    return self;
}
```

Comment: Doesn't Apple recommend against using accessors in init methods?

Answer (score 1):

If it's your own custom property then the XIB should be setting it to zero.

Therefore, as @cduhn said, you can modify it in:

```
- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)decoder {
    if (self = [super initWithCoder:decoder]) {
        lineWidth = 12; // whatever value you want
    }
    return self;
}
```